# Jquery DOM navigation select parent attr

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a better way of doing this:

```
partId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('data-partid') ;
```

I have something where rows are outputted onto the page, each row contains input fields.

When the user keyups on an input field it saves the input to the database via ajax.

In order to make sure that the information gets saved to the correct row I need to send along the row id, which is stored in the div:

```
<div id="buyingRow0" data-partid="43293">...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way would be to do something like:

```
partId = $(this).closest('div[data-partid]').data('partid');
```

but I'm not sure it is any more efficient. It may even be slower.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `closest()`:

```
var partId = $(this).closest('div').attr('data-partid') ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your target div has an ID (and you're using the ID attribute correctly), it means it's the only one on the page.

```
$('#buyingRow0').data('partid');
```

Seems to make the most sense here.

Comment: Hi, the ids are dyamically generated and I don't think there is a different way to get the ID of the part row to what has been suggested from which ever input/select is altered within it.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).parent().parent()` says exactly two nodes up. Using `.closest()` as the rest advise is indeed good if you don't want to be too dependent on the DOM structure.

If `data-partid` is a generic attribute you add to a lot of your tags, it might also be good to add another boolean indicator for the row you are concerned with, eg. `data-buying-row`, so you can have other tags with `data-partid` within that node.

```
<div id="buyingRow0" data-partid="43293" data-buying-row>
  ...
</div>
```

In this case, you traverse up to that buying row:

```
$(this).closest('div[data-buying-row]').data('partid');
```